# Creating Dropdown List in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, html-helper

I am trying to create a dropdown list to display all the value in a custom collection class
such as

```
public class MyCustomClassCollection
{

public List<MyCustomClass> {get;set;}

}
```

I want it to show the Description:string of each MyCustomClass

I tried

```
<%: Html.DropDownList "Description", MyCustomClass %>
```

Resharper suggests that I cast MyCustomClass to IEnemerable

but the server returns an unable to cast error.

Any Idea how I can create this DropDownList?

__*Modification****_*__**

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public Detail detail { get; set; }
    }

public class Detail   //Inherited from webservce
{
   public CustomClassCollection {get;set;}
   .... Other Properties, a.k.a Custom Classes
}


public class CustomClassCollection
{
   public List<CustomClass> {get;set;}
}

public class CustomClass {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Description{get;set;}
  ... other properties

}


public ActionResult Index(int? id, DateTime? date)
        {
            if (id.Equals(null))
                id = ######### ;
            if (date.Equals(null))
                date = DateTime.Today;
            var vm = new ViewModel
                         {
                             Detail = _repository.Detail((int)id,(DateTime)date)
                         };
            return View(vm);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of the `DropDownList` helper must be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` or a `SelectList` which implements this interface for that matter. So in your controller action organize in such a way that you convert your custom collection into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. As always you could start by writing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedDescription { get; set; }
    public SelectList Descriptions { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action query the custom list and populate the view model which will be passed to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var descriptions = yourCustomCollection.MyCustomClass.Select(x => new
    {
        Value = x.Description,
        Text = x.Description
    });
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Descriptions = new SelectList(descriptions, "Value", "Text")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDescription, Model.Decriptions) %>
```

---

UPDATE:

After posting your updated models (which by the way are still incomplete and impossible to compile as you haven't provided any property names), here's an example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public Detail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
   public CustomClassCollection MyCollection { get; set; }
}


public class CustomClassCollection
{
   public List<CustomClass> CustomClass { get; set; }
}

public class CustomClass 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel
        {
            Detail = new Detail
            {
                MyCollection = new CustomClassCollection
                {
                    CustomClass = new List<CustomClass>
                    {
                        new CustomClass
                        {
                            Id = 1,
                            Description = "description 1",
                        },
                        new CustomClass
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            Description = "description 2",
                        },
                        new CustomClass
                        {
                            Id = 3,
                            Description = "description 3",
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Detail.MyCollection.CustomClass, "Id", "Description")
) %>
```

What you have to understand in order to define a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC ius that you need 2 things:

1. A scalar property to bind the selected value to (`SelectedId` in my example)
2. A collection to bind the list to (`Model.Detail.MyCollection.CustomClass` in the example)

Comment: That doesnt work I can not select past Custom collection. It then begins to give me options such as select,where...

Comment: @Antarr Byrd, how does this custom collection look like? The code you have shown won't even compile. Please provide a complete description of the objects involved in your objects hierarchy.

Comment: I will post modified code above, the data is being accessed via a webservice not LINQ

Comment: @Antarr Byrd, I have updated my answer to reflect on your modifications. All that is left is now to adapt this code to match your repository structure.

Comment: Lets say I have a repo function that calls GetCustomClassCollection from the webservice. How would I format that inside the controller

Comment: @Antarr Byrd, like this: `var vm = new ViewModel { Detail = new Detail { MyCollection = _repo.GetCustomClassCollection() } };`.

Comment: So where is the SelectedId set?

Comment: @Antarr Byrd, it's up to you to set it manually when initializing the `ViewModel` object. Simply set its `SelectedId` property in addition to the `Detail` property.

Comment: @Antarr Byrd, like this `var vm = new ViewModel { SelectedId = 123, Detail = new Detail { MyCollection = _repo.GetCustomClassCollection() } };` where `123` is the value you want to set it to. If you have an element in the collection with this id it will automatically preselect this item in the dropdown list.

Comment: Ok, 
The way I have it just auto increments I guess.