# Connecting list<object> to the dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am newbie in ASP.NET MVC3.
I have an Object and I want to bind a list of objects to the dropdownlist in a view.

```
public class Object
{
   public string Name {get; set; }
   public string Address {get; set;}
   public string Id {get; set;} 
}
```

I have a view which consists of dropdown and label to show address whatever name is selected 
I want to associate the name property from the object list to a dropdown. Assuming that we are getting the list from the sql server. I want to show the name list on the drop down and when the user chooses one of the name from the dropdown, it should show the address in the lable.

I don't know if everything above is  clear or not. can somebody please point me to any example ?

Thanks

Comment: I have created a view and also the viewmodel. But don't know how to associate the property from the object to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a couple of examples of questions already asked on Stack Overflow:

1) [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749241/dropdown-boxes-in-mvc-3)

2) [Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462424/creating-dropdown-list-in-mvc3)

Your probably going to get hammared for asking a similar question as the links above, but good luck hope this helps

Comment: Not a problem! If you could post some code of the view you have, then we could give you a more comprehensive answer.